# Re using existing volume at docker-compose ELK stack

Tags: docker, elastic-stack

I'm trying to re use an existing ES volume with several days of logs in it.
But can't figure it out how. Have little to zero experience with docker-compose.

While trying to run docker-compose up I get:

```
ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:245: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 17\""
Starting kibana ... error

ERROR: for kibana  Cannot start service kibana: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:245: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 17\""


ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:245: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 17\""


ERROR: for kibana  Cannot start service kibana: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:245: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 17\""

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here's my spec:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/config/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - kibana

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms6g-Xmx6g"
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  logstash:
    build: logstash/
    command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    container_name: logstash
    environment:
      - "LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m"

    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5044:5044"
    links:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    container_name: kibana
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config:/opt/kibana/config
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local
```

Also, I tried with:

```
volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/myfolder/elasticsearch/storage/'
```

version:

```
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
```

I created the volume:

```
docker volume create elasticsearch
```

and tried deleting that /var/lib/docker/volumes/xxxxx folder and do a symlink to my volume, but didn't do it.

Is it possible? I have the volume attached to the host, there are no other things running nor older images/volumes. It will be only ELK stack with this volume with existing data in it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you start elasticsearch on its own: `docker run -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0` ?

Comment: No, tried a previous one and same result:
`docker run -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:245: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 17\"".`

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with your docker installation. Can you start other containers?

Comment: Had to upgrade kernel, was using 3.10 and now with 5, it works, I prefer doing so instead of downgrading docker version. I'm running centos 7. I'm now trying to get it running, kibana it's "Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"" and " Elasticsearch plugin is red".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we couldn't  re index the data with the volume attached, we decided to start from scratch, newer versions, built another docker-compose file and make filebeat pick up the logs files from servers. Downside, those imported logs got the date from when they were imported, but there's a timestamp at one of the fields with actual date.